# Is there a way to combine these strings then make each comma value a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The problem im up against at the moment is the need to take a data frame that looks like this

```
Column 1            Column 2 
"A"                 "B,C,D,E"
"T"                 "X,R,S"
```

and to make it look more like this

```
Column 1
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
...
```

I am trying to do this using Pandas, but I haven't found a way to reliably get the values into that same column.

Comment: do you have just two columns, and you want one of them to explode into the first one? Values separated by a comma turned into rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `stack` and `explode`:

```
output = df.stack().droplevel(1).str.split(",").explode().reset_index(drop=True)

>>> output
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    T
6    X
7    R
8    S
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `join`, `split` and `explode`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A', 'T'], 'col2':['B,C,D,E', 'X,R,S']})
df.apply(','.join, axis=1).str.split(',').explode(ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    T
6    X
7    R
8    S
dtype: object
```